# Optimal solution of $\max f(x)$ subject to $g(x)\geq 0, x\geq 0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> What can we say about the optimal solution (if exists) of the following nonlinear programming: $\max f(x)$ subject to $g(x)\geq 0, x\geq 0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and functions $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}_+$ is differentiable and bounded.

I have no idea on finding the optimal solution. Can anyone give me some hints? Thank you in advance!

Comment: See [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions).

Comment: Of course, there is no guarantee that an optimal solution exists.

Comment: Dear Prof. Robert, thank you for your answer. What if I assume that the optimal solution exist?

Comment: Then (assuming a constraint qualification condition) it satisfies the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions.

Comment: Do you have any specific problem?